# Why setting SSR to false is breaking my styles in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a Nextjs app. I have used it to build the Coinbase clone. Since it uses `window` object to connect to metamsk, I need to disable the SSR in Nextjs. But some how if I disable the SSR and restart the server it's breaking my styles. Take a look below, check how the style of Navbar title `Assets` changes when I disable SSR and restart the dev server:

With SSR enabled:
[image: With SSR enabled in Nextjs]

With SSR disabled:
[image: SSR disabled]

Here's my `_app.js`:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import { ChainId, ThirdwebProvider } from "@thirdweb-dev/react";
import { MoralisProvider } from "react-moralis";
import NoSSR from "./NoSSR";
import '../styles/globals.css'

const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
    background:{
      dark:'#0a0b0d',
    }
  },
});

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <NoSSR>
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <CssBaseline/>
      {/* <ThirdwebProvider desiredChainId={ChainId.Rinkeby}>
      </ThirdwebProvider> */}
      <MoralisProvider serverUrl={'https://124a8yab5jee.usemoralis.com:2053/server'} appId='Seyf64uxlgqgxt5Y75p1M4Hq21CC5osXcvj4T8Yw'>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      </MoralisProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
    </NoSSR>
  )
}

export default MyApp;
```

`NoSSR.js`:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import React from 'react'

const NoSsr = props => (
  <React.Fragment>{props.children}</React.Fragment>
)   

export default dynamic(() => Promise.resolve(NoSsr), {
  ssr: false
})
```

I am not getting why it's happening, is it a bug in Nextjs? I am also using Material UI libaray.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you used `NoSSR` in your `_app.js` and as a wrapper for the whole project means you don't want SSR option for any part of your code which is confusing because if you don't need SSR you don't have to go through `nextjs`. If you have a single component that needs to run on client side I suggest you only wrap that component on your `NoSSR`.

Also I suggest to put your `globals.css` in `src` folder (src is in root)